# Bibtex finished with 3 error messages

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm trying to compile a short essay with its bibliography. I'm in AUCTeX under Win 7. This is the route to follow, isn't it?

1. compile `main.tex` with `pdflatex`
2. launch BibTex on main.tex (this generates `main.aux`)
3. compile main.tex with pdflatex *twice*

I'm getting this error message

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
>   The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux I found no \citation
>   commands---while reading file main.aux I found no \bibdata
>   command---while reading file main.aux I found no \bibstyle
>   command---while reading file main.aux (There were 3 error messages)
>
> TeX Output exited abnormally with code 2 at Sat Sep 24

Here's a MWE. Where am I going wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[useprefix, style=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{articles}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %with "twoside" \documentclass option!!
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left if Even, Right if Odd pg
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Urban Gardens}
\fancyfoot[]{} %
\fancyfoot[]{}


% FONT CHOICE
% Palatino for serif & math, Helvetica for ss, Courier for tt
\usepackage{mathpazo} % math & rm
\linespread{1.50}     % Palatino needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
\normalfont

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{subcaption} % \begin{subfigure} within 'figure' environment
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize, italian]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\frenchspacing

% \graphicspath{{./img/}}

\title{My Essay}
\author{WW}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle{}
% \tableofcontents
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

The bibliography `articles.bib` has only 2 records. Can you please help me detect errors?

Comment: Since you have the directive `\usepackage[..., backend=biber,...]{biblatex}`, why are you running bibtex? You should be running biber instead. Also, consider changing `\bibliography{articles}` to `\addbibresource{articles.bib}`.

Comment: Can you please add the bib file to your question?

Comment: As Mico says, if you use `biblatex` (especially with `backend=biber`) you need to run Biber and not BibTeX. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help with your editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

```
>This is the route to follow, isn't it?
>    compile main.tex with pdflatex       [this generates main.aux]
>    launch BibTex on main                [this generates main.bbl]
>    compile main.tex with pdflatex twice [this incorporates main.bbl into the pdf file]
```

This would indeed be the route to follow *if* your document were using BibTeX. However, since your document uses the `biblatex` package with the option `backend=biber`, you should be running biber, *not* BibTeX. For your document, then, the correct sequence is:

```
> run pdfLaTeX on main[.tex]
> run biber on main
> run pdfLaTeX on main
```

Incidentally, you should replace the deprecated instruction `\bibliography{articles}` with

```
\addbibresource{articles.bib}
```

Two comments about the linespread choice: (a) Don't manipulate the low-level TeX parameter `\linespread` directly. Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue the directive `\setstretch{1.5}`. (b) One indeed does encounter the recommendation that leading should be slightly looser with a `Palatino` font. However, that recommendation is generally for a factor around 1.04 or 1.05, *never* 1.5! If you absolute must increase the leading, by all means to do. Just don't claim you're doing so because `Palatino` somehow requires it...

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{articles.bib}
@misc{a:3001,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Initial Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{z:3002,
  author = "Zo{\"e} Zwicky",
  title  = "Final Thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[useprefix, style=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt, 
            backend=biber, hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{articles.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %with "twoside" \documentclass option!!
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left if Even, Right if Odd pg
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Urban Gardens}
\fancyfoot[]{} %
\fancyfoot[]{}


% FONT CHOICE
% Palatino for serif & math, Helvetica for ss, Courier for tt
\usepackage{mathpazo} % math & rm

%%%\linespread{1.50}     % Palatino needs more leading (space between lines)
% Don't set the low-level parameter "\linespread" directly!
% Instead, load the "setspace" package and state "\setstretch{1.5}"
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
\normalfont

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{subcaption} % \begin{subfigure} within 'figure' environment
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize, italian]{cleveref}

\frenchspacing

% \graphicspath{{./img/}}

\title{My Essay}
\author{WW}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle{}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\lipsum[2]

%\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```